# Syntax for putting an onClick action in an echo statement

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, echo

What would be the correct syntax for the onClick attribute in the following:

```
    <?php 

    if($_resp['user']) {

    echo '<div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Join', 'Home', 'BigButton']);">Link Text</a>';        

 }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are nesting both double and single quotes, you will need to escape the single quotes in the `onClick` with backslashes.

```
echo '<div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Join\', \'Home\', \'BigButton\']);">Link Text</a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a HEREDOC

```
if ($_resp['user']) {
   echo <<<EOL
<div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Join', 'Home', 'BigButton']);">Link Text</a>

EOL;
}
```

or dropping out of PHP mode:

```
if ($_resp['user']) { ?>
<div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Join', 'Home', 'BigButton']);">Link Text</a>

<?php }
```

Both get the job done, and eliminate any need to escape quotes inside the html/javascript you're generating

Comment: are there any reasons not to use escape quotes?

Comment: escapes are supposed to be an exception/one-time thing. Having to escape THAT much makes for painful reading down the line, plus the inevitable time you miss a quote, don't escape it, and wonder at the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix HTML and PHP, so you might want to simply move it out of PHP:

```
<?php 

if($_resp['user']) {

?>

<div class="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Join', 'Home', 'BigButton']);">Link Text</a>

<?       

}

?>
```